# "Without whom..." or "whom ... without"?

Tags: expressions, prepositions, word-order

Is it more grammatically correct to move the preposition *without* to the end of its clause, or use *without whom*? Does the "in no particular order" change matters?

> I wish to express my sincere gratitude to people **without whom it would
>   not be possible to complete the work**, in no particular order.

vs.

> I wish to express my sincere gratitude to people **whom it would
>   not be possible to complete the work without**, in no particular order.

Comment: I think either is grammatical (except to those who argue against ending a phrase with a preposition), but the first is the usual way to say it.

Comment: It's more grammatically correct to avoid using _whom_. Especially if you have any question at all about any case where it is used. It's always possible to avoid it, and if you do use it, half the people who hear it will assume you're incorrect, even if you use it correctly. That's because most people have questions. So it should be avoided and allowed to die a decent death, like _ye_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Whilst I usually have the utmost respect for your grasp of English grammar, I cannot agree with you here. You will see my answer below. Are you seriously saying I should say *...without **who** it would not have been possible*? In the company I keep ***whom*** is in everyday use. (I don't think ***ye*** was ever a word was it? Wasn't it simply that *y* was an earlier way of writing *th*? But it was never pronounced as we would pronounce a *y*, is my understanding.)

Comment: @WS2: No, I said to avoid it. That includes avoiding pied-piping prepositions when using _who_ as a relative pronoun (i.e, you could say _that it wouldn't've been possible without_, using _that_ and leaving a stranded preposition).  Pied-piping is the only construction where _whom_ is required in English. It's optional everywhere else. So, if you avoid the stuffy construction, you avoid the stuffy pronoun too, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @JohnLawler But isn't *stuffiness* in the eye of the beholder?

Comment: In the ear of the listener. It makes the speaker sound overformal, like a non-native speaker afraid of uttering a solecism. Or someone who believes every myth they were taught in grammar school and hasn't thought about grammar since. Or both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Do English Speakers Use "Preposition + Relative Pronoun" Form?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237462/why-do-english-speakers-use-preposition-relative-pronoun-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is far preferable to the second, in my view.

However I would still make some minor amendments to that in the interests of concision and clarity. This would be my suggested wording:

*I wish to express my sincere gratitude to **those** people without whom it would not be possible to complete the work. In no particular order they are:...*

Finally, I am slightly surprised that you are using the present conditional tense. Usually these sorts of things are said after the event. Hence I am wondering if *would not be possible* should read *would not have been possible*.