# Should this relative clause start with "whom" or "to whom"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage

Which of the following sentences is correct according to English grammar and usage? (Note: this was asked in an examination and I have to select only one of the four sentences.)

> 1) The fishermen, **whom** the flood victims owed their lives, were rewarded by the government.
>
> 2) The fishermen, **to which** the flood victims owed their lives, were rewarded by the government.
>
> 3) The fishermen, **to whom** the flood victims owed their lives, were rewarded by the government.
>
> 4) The fishermen, **that** the flood victims owed their lives, were rewarded by the government.

I think it is 1) or 3), but I’m not sure which. Is “to” required before “whom” in a sentence like this?

Comment: Both are fine. You can even say: *The fisherman, **whom** the river victims owed their lives **to**, were rewarded…* (note the extra comma)

Comment: See this answer https://english.stackexchange.com/a/237463/44619

Comment: Related: [“Without whom…” or “whom … without”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242055/without-whom-or-whom-without?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I don't like (1). But you could use *The fisherman, who the river victims owed their lives to, were rewarded by the government.*

Comment: What are your views about (2) @PeterShor

Comment: Yeah, #1 is not good.

Comment: I actually think (1) is fine grammatically. I think it sounds wrong to me because dropping the *to*, which is grammatically acceptable, and which would be fine in shorter sentences, makes this one more difficult to parse. For example, I don't see anything wrong with *The man whom I owed ten dollars.*

Comment: Both sentences are poorly punctuated and ungrammatical. This is not English. Don't take this exam, run away.

Comment: @PeterShor In that case, 'The man' is the object of the verb 'owed'. In this case, the verb is 'were rewarded' and the fishermen are the subject of the verb. It is important to distinguish the relative clause here.

Comment: @Deonyi: If you insist, we can complete the relative clause to the sentence: *The man whom I owed ten dollars won the lottery yesterday.* I don't see anything wrong with that sentence, either.

Comment: @RegDwigнt i have edited the question. is it correct now?

Comment: Note that this is ***not*** a duplicate of the question people are about to close it as a duplicate as. That one is on the difference between *to whom* and *whom .... to*. This one is about the difference between *to whom* and *whom ...* (no *to*).

Comment: There's still the problem of the plural verb (were) not agreeing with the subject (the fisherMAN) which escaped my attention the first time. Who was rewarded? The fisherman or the river / flood victims?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the same question, with the same mistakes: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/484416/question-asked-in-an-exam#comment1169518_484416 However, it was closed and has no accepted answers.

Comment: @PeterShor I honestly have no idea what I was thinking back then regarding relative clauses, objects and subjects. Maybe it will come to me. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to choose only one option from "whom the river victims owed their lives" and "to whom the river victims owed their lives", go with "to whom the river victims owed their lives". This version of the relative clause is undeniably grammatical in standard written English. Putting a prepositional phrase containing a *wh*-word at the front of a relative clause is called "pied-piping" by linguists; it is relatively formal and may sound stilted in conversational English, but it wouldn't be considered "incorrect" in the context of an examination that is testing your mastery of standard written English.

There is less clarity about the status of clauses like "whom the river victims owed their lives". In this relative clause, the word "whom" represents the "indirect object" of the verb *owe.* Some sources say that *wh*-fronting of indirect objects is ungrammatical, or at least "infelicitous". For specific references, see [my answer to *Is “Whom did you give the book?”  ungrammatical?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/304048/77227) Different speakers seem to have different judgements of the acceptability of clauses with fronted *wh*-words functioning as indirect objects.

Comment: you are right. i made some mistake and sorry for that.. i am now editing the question with exact sentences.. please look again at the question.. again am very sorry for that.

Comment: @empty-soul "some" mistakes?  You left out some of the punctuation, you forgot about the other two options, you omitted the fact that it came from a test paper. Better late than never I suppose, so I've retracted my downvote. However, it means Sumelic answer only discusses the difference between 1 and 3.

Comment: Examination was online and question paper was not released until then. What i have written previously in question was memory based. Yesterday i got the question paper and hence corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that all four edited examples are in error. The singular subject "fisherman" requires a singular verb "was."

Comment: oh,, then have a look at this picture https://imgur.com/a/mhlguhu .. it was exact question that was asked..

Comment: i have edited.. it was actually fishermen